# Why doesn't updating the graph dynamically through pointers work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve number-of-connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph from Leetcode. And I thought that I can solve this by updating the graph dynamically with pointers. So for example If I have 1->2, then have 2->3, then 1 should be updated to 3, since 1 -> 2 and 2 is 3. So for edges=[[0,1],[1,2],[2, 3],[4, 5]], the  result should be {1: 3, 0: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 5: 5, 4: 5}, but the current code I have gives me {1: 2, 0: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 5: 5, 4: 5}. The fault is that 0 does not get updated to the new value of 1 and 1 does not get updated to the new value of 2, why?

What I am doing in the code is that, if a value points to something, point to the value of it in the dict, but if a value does not point to anything then it points to itself, but if it points to something different that itself later, it can be updated.

```
graph = {}
for key, val in edges:
    if graph.get(val) == None:
        graph[val] = val
    graph[key] = graph[val]
    if graph.get(key) == key:
        graph[key] = graph[val]
print(graph)
```

Comment: This is something you should be able to easily debug visually at http://pythontutor.com.